# PHP display mysql result based on date picker input

Tags: php, mysql

I have two pages `index4.php` and `generate.php`. User have to select a date range and click on button in `index4.php` to generate user report in `generate.php`.

index4.php
[image: index4.php]

database table
[image: database table]

And I wish to display those results in `generate.php` something like this:
[image: result table]

Here is my coding for both pages: 
`index4.php`

```
<form action="generate.php" method="post" target="_blank">
    <table width="528" align="center" boder="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="109">Select date :</td>
        <td width="202">FROM&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="date" name="start_date" required/></td>
        <td width="24">TO</td>
        <td width="173">&nbsp;<input type="date" name="end_date" required/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><i><font color="#FF0000">*</font>&nbsp;Required field.</i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="4" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Generate User Report"/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

`generate.php`

```
<table align="center" border="1">
<tr>
    <td align="center">Date</td>
    <td align="center">Page Name</td>
    <td align="center">Page Viewed</td>
</tr>
<?php
    if(mysql_num_rows($select_page_view) > 0)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($select_page_view); ?>
        <tr>
            <?php $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($select_page_view); ?>
            <td rowspan="<?php echo $num_rows; ?>"><?php echo $row['page_view_date']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        while($row)
        {?>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['page_name'];?></td><td><?php echo $row['visited_times']; ?></td>
            </tr>
  <?php } ?>
<?php }?>
</table>
```

When I test my `generate.php` and **the page shows infinite loop for `page_name`**... any solution to solve it?

Comment: You need to [stop using mysql_ functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) as they are removed in PHP7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the loop in this way:

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($select_page_view) )
{
    (...)
}
```

In your original syntax:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($select_page_view);
(...)
while( $row )
{
    (...)
}
```

`$row` is fetched one, then it doesn't change, so the loop doesn't stop.